# How can I get the data from JSON code with PHP?

Tags: php, json

The data comes [from here](http://elofight.com/code.php).

I want to print the wins from `"playerStatSummaryType": "RankedSolo5x5"` so how can I get the data from RankedSolo5x5?

This is my code:

```
$claw = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/summary?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0r = file_get_contents($claw);
$gaza = json_decode($z0r, true);
$wins = $gaza['playerStatSummaries'][4]['wins'];
print $wins;
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far to get it to print, and explain a bit more how you want it to be presented. At this stage I would recommend you Google json to PHP. At least show some level of attempt or you won't get an answer

Comment: I blame temporary blindness? You are correct, my question made no sense!

Answer (score 1):

```
$wins = $gaza['playerStatSummaries'][4];
echo $key = array_search('RankedSolo5x5', $wins);
```

It will return you its type name

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way. Since the JSON data format is odd, rolling through the returned 'playerStatSummaries' array and acting on the 'playerStatSummaryType' that equals 'RankedSolo5x5' seems like the best future-proof solution:

```
$claw = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/summary?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0r = file_get_contents($claw);
$gaza = json_decode($z0r, true);

// Roll through the 'playerStatSummaries' array & act on the 'playerStatSummaryType' that equals 'RankedSolo5x5'.
$wins = '';
foreach ($gaza['playerStatSummaries'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['playerStatSummaryType'] == 'RankedSolo5x5') {
    $wins = $value['wins'];
  }
}

// Return the value of `$wins`.
echo $wins;

// Check the output of `$gaza` for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($gaza);
echo '</pre>';
```

I also added the `print_r($gaza);` so you can actually see what data is being returned from the call. Visualizing the output is the best way to debug a process like this.

The structure of the array is shown to be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [summonerId] => 43216818
    [playerStatSummaries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [playerStatSummaryType] => AramUnranked5x5
                    [wins] => 41
                    [modifyDate] => 1405178930000
                    [aggregatedStats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalChampionKills] => 632
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 26
                            [totalAssists] => 1491
                        )

                )
```

And the data point you are looking to act on is this:

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [playerStatSummaryType] => RankedTeam3x3
        [wins] => 4
        [losses] => 1
        [modifyDate] => 1381833912000
        [aggregatedStats] => Array
            (
                [totalChampionKills] => 33
                [totalMinionKills] => 319
                [totalTurretsKilled] => 6
                [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 33
                [totalAssists] => 44
            )

    )
```