# How can I get the data from JSON code with PHP?

Tags: php, json

i just want get the data from the json link with the id == 0

how  i can make this !?

```
<?php
$claw = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0r = file_get_contents($claw);
$gaza = json_decode($z0r, true);
foreach ($gaza['champions'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['id'] == 0) {
    $wins = $value['totalTripleKills'];
  }
}
?>
```

my code doesn't show anything ..

can anyone help !?

Comment: And that… didn’t work? What happened?

Comment: only blank page :( ,, nothing show !

Comment: Well, you’re not producing any output.

Comment: Put ini_set('display_errors', 1); right after the <?php open tag.

Comment: i know there's bad in my code :( ,, how i can fix it !?

Comment: no, is this all your code?  The whole thing, because that wont output anything.

Comment: i use this and it's work but i can't do the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715134/how-can-i-get-the-data-from-json-code-with-php#

Answer (score 2):

Your not outputing anything, your just assigning `$wins` over and over, there could also be an issue with file_get_contents not working as expected with over https urls.

Its faster and easyier to use cURL, also after a quick test it seems,

`$value['totalTripleKills']` should be `$value['stats']['totalTripleKills']`

```
<?php
$url = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if(empty($result)) {
    echo 'Error fetching: '.htmlentities($url).' '.curl_error($curl);

}else{

    $gaza = json_decode($result, true);

    foreach ($gaza['champions'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id'] == 0) {
            echo $value['stats']['totalTripleKills'].'<br>';
        }
    }

}
```

Also its a rather large response so you will want to look into caching the result for a while, but thats beyond the questions scope.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error you forgot to enter first in the stats array, otherwise you cannot take `totalTripleKills` value, then output it.

```
$claw = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0r = file_get_contents($claw);
$gaza = json_decode($z0r, true);
foreach ($gaza['champions'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['id'] == 0) {
    $wins = $value['stats']['totalTripleKills'];
  }
}
echo $wins;
```

Before you parse a json a helpful method to understand json structure of your data is this website: http://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: how i can contact you ,, i want ur help in something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718215/how-i-get-the-data-from-json-code-in-php

Answer (score -1):

your not outputting anything,

```
<?php
$claw = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0r = file_get_contents($claw);
$gaza = json_decode($z0r, true);
foreach ($gaza['champions'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['id'] == 0) {
    $wins = $value['totalTripleKills'];
  }
}
?>
```

try this

```
<?php
$claw = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/43216818/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0r = file_get_contents($claw);
$gaza = json_decode($z0r, true);

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($gaza['champions'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['id'] == 0) {
    $wins = $value['totalTripleKills'];
    var_export( $wins );
  }
} 



?>
```